# Easy method to print entire treeview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, wpf-controls

I have a treeview object with checkboxes in my application and I need to print the entire treeview structure . How do I do this? I tried visual control printing but it doesn't satisfy my requirement since the tree is so long. I tried some of the codes from other sites, but none of them satisfies the requirement. I am using framework V 3.5. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance,
Sivajith

Comment: When i needed to do same task i used devexpress controls

Comment: is that free of cost?

Answer (score -2):

To iterate through all nodes of the TreeView control:
1.Create a recursive method that tests each node.
2.Call the procedure. 
The following example shows how to print each TreeNode object's Text property:

```
private void PrintRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
{
  // Print the node.
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(treeNode.Text);
  MessageBox.Show(treeNode.Text);
  // Print each node recursively.
  foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
  {
    PrintRecursive(tn);
  }
}

// Call the procedure using the TreeView.
private void CallRecursive(TreeView treeView)
{
   // Print each node recursively.
   TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;
   foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
   {
    PrintRecursive(n);
   }
 }
```

Comment: this code does not appear to do any printing. at all.

Comment: There is PrintRecursive in the code. The name says it. It prints.

Comment: That you named your method "PrintRecursive" doesn't mean it _prints_. The only output your code does is to write text to the debug output, and to display text in a message box. Neither of these are _printing_, i.e. as the tag describes: _"Printing is a process for reproducing text and images, typically with ink or toner, on paper using a printer"_.

Comment: I have check boxes in my treeview.. My requirement is print the exact treeview structure

Comment: I need something like PrintDialog.PrintVisual Method  but need to print the entire tree structure , not the visible portion